Is it statistically appropriate to aggregate indexes?
I would like to know if aggregating indexes is statistically appropriate.
Specifically, I would like to aggregate the CDC’s social vulnerability index (SVI): https://www.atsdr.cdc.gov/placeandhealth/svi/documentation/SVI_documentation_2022.html.
The SVI indexes are provided at the census tract level for the US, where census tracts are subdivisions of counties for which the Census collects statistical data. I would like to know the SVI index for a group of census tracts. These groups would be smaller than a county and the groups will make up a county. Hence, these groups of census tracts would be larger than a census tract but smaller than a county.
I want to know if it would be statistically sound for me to aggregate these indexes by averaging the indexes. My intention is to do this aggregation for groups of census tracts for a single county within a State.

The Social Vulnerability Index (SVI) is already computed as an aggregated index determined by the population rates for a set of sixteen underlying conditions in the region at issue.  There is inevitably going to be some arbitrariness in aggregating these underlying conditions into an overall ranking, so the SVI itself is a statistical measure that involves a certain degree of subjectivity in the rankings.
Ideally, if you wanted to obtain the SVI for the aggregate of a set of tracts, you would aggregate the underlying data on the sixteen conditions at issue and then compute the SVI for that underlying data for the larger aggregated region.
Because of differences in population, and the mapping of percentiles to rankings, the aggregate of the SVI is not typically equal to the SVI of the aggregate --- i.e., the aggregate SVI of a set of tracts will not typically be equal to the SVI of the aggregated set of tracts (computed from the underlying data for that larger area).
